# Index of frequency larger than power spectrum length

Tags: signal-processing, signal-to-noise

I am new in this community. So excuse me if it seems easy.

I want to calculate the amplitude of a specific frequency in a signal.
The frequency precision is ([relevant question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/12412/191750))
$$
df = \frac{fs}{NP}
$$ 
$$ fs=1/dt$$ 
NP is the number of points in the signal time seri.
The index of the frequency in the signal is 
$$
ind = \frac{f}{df}
$$
the length of power spectrum array of signal is `length(pxx) = NP/2-1`

**Example 1: for small frequencies**

```
frequency = 1.0/128.0    
dt=0.4
df = 0.001
NP = fs/df=2500
index of the signal = 8
```

lenght of pxx is 1249 so no problem.

**Example 2: for large frequencies**

```
freq = 2.0    
dt=0.4
NP = fs/df=2500
index of the signal = 2000
```

The index of the frequency is larger than the number of points in pxx. 
If I double the number of points in the signal, the frequency precision halves and the index of frequency also doubles.
Is there a frequency limit or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks for any guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (with constant sampling frequency) will only give information about the signal up to a frequency of

$$f = \frac{f_s}{2} = f_N$$

\$f_N\$ is called the **Nyquist frequency**. Frequencies in the signal higher than \$f_N\$ are subject to **aliasing** (related to the *Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem*).

So if you want to find information about a certain frequency \$f_x\$, you will need at least a sampling frequency of \$f_s > 2\cdot f_x\$ and extra to accommodate for an anti-alias filter.

Increasing the number of points will only increase the resolution, without changing the Nyquist frequency.